# Which Luadist files needed for distribution

Tags: lua, iup

I have installed Luadist and created a small program (named abcd.lua which also uses IUP GUI). It runs well with command `iuplua.exe abcd.lua` I want to give it to some other persons to try. Since Lua may not be installed on their computer, I want to give it to them with Luadist folder. I see that there are a large number of files in Luadist folder (1148 to be exact- tried listing them here but it exceeds character count). They are in following folders:

```
bin : has large number of exe and dll files.
include: has lauxlib.h  luaconf.h  lua.h  lua.hpp  lualib.h
lib: has liblua.dll.a and its extracted folder and a lua folder with large number of subfolders and files
share: also has large number of folders and files.
tmp: only empty cache folder currently
```

Following files contain 'iup' in their names:

```
./share/luadist-git/dists/iup-3.6
./share/luadist-git/dists/iup-3.6/dist.info
./share/iup
./share/iup/README
./share/iup/COPYRIGHT
./lib/lua/iupluaimglib.dll
./lib/lua/iuplua.dll
./lib/lua/iuplua_mglplot.dll
./lib/lua/iupluacd.dll
./lib/lua/iupluacontrols.dll
./lib/lua/iupluagl.dll
./lib/lua/iuplua_pplot.dll
./lib/lua/iupluatuio.dll
./lib/lua/iupluaim.dll
./bin/libiuptuio.dll
./bin/libiup_pplot.dll
./bin/iuplua.exe
./bin/iupview.exe
./bin/libiup.dll
./bin/libiupgl.dll
./bin/libiupcd.dll
./bin/libiupim.dll
./bin/libiupimglib.dll
./bin/libiup_mglplot.dll
./bin/libiuplua.dll
./bin/libiupcontrols.dll
```

Will giving only these file alongwith my program file (abcd.lua) be sufficient, though I think many dll files will also be needed?

Which files or folders can I select to give or do I need to give all files for proper running of my program? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

(1) move the executable to a different folder and start your script. It will fails with an error message about a missing DLL; move the DLL to the folder with the executable and repeat. This should give you a list of the dependencies, assuming the execution will follow all code paths that load external modules.

(2) use the [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find all dependencies that your executable and its DLLs have. The advantage of this method is that you can execute it without moving any files and it will give you a detailed analysis of the dependencies and how they are resolved on your system.

Keep in mind that you don't need to preserve the same structure that LuaDist has for the dynamic libraries; you can put all the DLLs your script needs next to the executable (and this is likely to be the simplest and the most successful configuration).

Comment: Dependency Walker work by looking at the executable or DLL for linked dependencies. Since Lua will dynamically load the modules, it will not work. Unless you manually open each module DLL to see its dependencies.

Comment: Dependency Walker will work as it includes profiling feature that tracks everything that is loaded by the script (that includes everything loaded dynamically).

Comment: Hah, OK. When you "Start Profiling" yes.

Answer (score 1):

In the IUP documentation, each library describes its dependencies. You can start there.

But the answer depends on what modules are you using. If the only "require" you do is "iup", then it is quite simple. You will need the executable, the Lua DLL, the IUP DLL and the IUPLUA DLL.

Comment: I think I will also need iuplua.exe. Do I need to include lua.exe or any other exe?

Comment: That's what I meant, you need one executable. It can be iuplua.exe or lua.exe both will work the same when running a lua file from the command line. They are very different when running without parameters.